# Vue draggable not updating index

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onchange, v-for, vuedraggable

I'm using  Vue draggable to drag lists between categories:

```
<draggable v-bind="dragOptions" @change="dragCat">
   <div v-for="cat in categories" :key="cat.id">
      <draggable v-model="cat.lists" v-bind="dragOptions" 
         group="categories" @change="dragList(cat)">
         <div v-for="list in cat.lists" :key="list.id">
            {{list.title}}
         </div>
      </draggable>
   </div>
</draggable>
```

```
import draggable from "vuedraggable";
var vm = new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   components: {
      draggable
   },
   data() {
      return {
         categories: [
            {lists: [{title: "A"}, {title: "B"}]},
            {lists: [{title: "C"}, {title: "D"}]},
            {lists: [{title: "E"}, {title: "F"}]},
         ],
      }
   },
   methods: {
      dragCat() {
         // Loop through categories with index
         ...
      },
      dragList(cat) {
         // Loop through cat.lists with index
         ...
      },
   }
   ....
});
```

Because of group in the inner draggable I can drag between categories. But the outer draggable is not working, the change method is not called.  When I use change instead, the categories do get moved and the function is called BUT the index in the loop is not updating.

Means: Initial 0(A,B) - 1(C,D) - 2 (E,F)
I'll switch 0 and 1: 
Expected: 0(C,D) - 1(A,B) - 2(E,F)
Reality: 1(C,D) - 0(A,B) - 2(E-F)

So I cannot send new index to database, means, when I move categories and refresh, it's back on initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not binding categories to the outer draggable, adding v-model to first draggable will fix the issue, v-model="categories"

also Using the proper key in a list may help, Vue needs the key to identify any change to a list

Comment: yes it's working, silly mistake by me, feelding dumb now, thanks. But my key is correct I just did not set the id to that array since my data is actually coming from database and I forgot it in that reconstruction. It was just the missing v-model. Thank you!